# Existe alguma maneira pythônico de fazer "slice" de um array?

Tags: python, dicionário

Em *JavaScript* existe o [**`Array.prototype.slice`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
var input = [ 'laranja', 'limão', 'melancia', 'mamão' ];

var aparada = input.slice(1, -1);

console.log( aparada );
```

E no *PHP* o [**`array_slice`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$input = array( 'laranja', 'limão', 'melancia', 'mamão' );

print_r( array_slice($input, 0, -1) );
```

Como poderia fazer isto em Python, de maneira mais simplificada?

Answer (score 9):

O Python tem a função [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice), mas creio que a maneira mais simplificada de se extrair um conjunto de elemento, deve se utilizar a mesma notação para obter um único elemento: `lista[<Índice>]`, porém deve informar o intervalo desejado: `lista[<Inicio>:<Fim>]`

```
input = [ 'laranja', 'limão', 'melancia', 'mamão' ]
print(input[1:-1])
```

> Exemplo online [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FrigidImpossibleIndianjackal)

Continuando a mesma notação acima, existe o terceiro parâmetro que é o **passo**: `lista[<Inicio>:<Fim>:<Passo>]`, o **passo** tem seu valor inicial como **1**, e se informado o valor **0** será lançado uma **exceção** igual a essa:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: slice step cannot be zero
```

Exemplo com **passo**:

```
numeros = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(numeros[::2]) # Impares
print(numeros[1::2]) # Pares
```

> Exemplo online [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/InsubstantialDimpledXeme)

Exemplo utilizando a função `slice`.

```
input = [ 'laranja', 'limão', 'melancia', 'mamão' ]
print(input[slice(1,-1)])
```

> Exemplo online [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AmpleAngryFishingcat)

Exemplo utilizando **passo** na função `slice`.

```
numeros = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
print(numeros[slice(None,None,2)]) # Impares
print(numeros[slice(1,None,2)]) # Pares
```

> Exemplo online [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/UtterTomatoBlacklab)

Comment: a "função" `slice` do Python mencionada no primeiro parágrafo não é usada como indicado. Ela apenas constrói um objeto "slice" que é usado internamente para pegar sessões de sequências, como explicado no restante da resposta. Em geral só é usada se você está implementando uma classe de sequência que funciona como uma lista.

Comment: Faz sentido o que você disse @jsbueno, até porque uma hora ou outra iriamos precisar do método slice.indices para evitar tratamento de erro.

Comment: @jsbueno agradeço o *feedback*, sou meio leigo em *Python*, e confesso que fiquei confuso quando encontrei na documentação sobre essa função, até crie agora pouco uma pergunta sobre a mesma: [Dúvida sobre a função slice](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/265588)