# Dúvida sobre a função slice

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Ao [responder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/265103/60376) essa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/265066) que o *Guilherme Nascimento P.* fez, abriu-se uma dúvida quanto ao uso da função [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice), até o momento eu não tinha conhecimento da mesma, e ao acha-lá na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) fiquei confuso.

Pesquisando aqui no *SOpt* não encontrei nada a respeito, os termos usados na pesquisa foram: [[python] função slice](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o+slice) e [[python] slice](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+slice).

Nosso amigo @jsbueno [comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/265066/existe-alguma-maneira-pyth%C3%B4nico-de-fazer-slice-de-um-array/265103#comment544062_265103):

> a "função" slice do Python mencionada no primeiro parágrafo não é usada como indicado. Ela apenas constrói um objeto "slice" que é usado internamente para pegar sessões de sequências, como explicado no restante da resposta. Em geral só é usada se você está implementando uma classe de sequência que funciona como uma lista.

Minha dúvida é: Como é o uso correto da função [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) ?

```
input = [ 'laranja', 'limão', 'melancia', 'mamão' ]
print(input[slice(1,-1)])
```

> **Obs.:** Quanto as tags da pergunta, se estiver faltando alguma só avisar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A chamada built-in `slice` do Python não é propriamente uma função - como algumas outras chamadas do Python, ela é na verdade uma classe que cria o objeto `slice`.

As chances de você precisar usar `slice`diretamente são bem pequenas, mas há alguns usos - em geral mais para você verificar se um objeto é um `slice` e usa-lo, do que para criar um diretamente.

O objeto slice é o que é usado internamente pelo Python quando se usa a "notação de fatia" (slice notation) para delimitar um subconjunto de uma sequência, como uma lista ou uma string.

Essa notação nada mais é do que usar números separados por `:` dentro de um par de colchetes `[  ]` usado como índice - como fazemos em:

```
In [70]: a = "banana"

In [71]: a[1:4]
Out[71]: 'ana'
```

Ou

```
In [72]: b = list(range(10, 20))

In [73]: b
Out[73]: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

In [74]: b[:-5:2]
Out[74]: [10, 12, 14]
```

(nesse caso, a fatia `[:-5:2]`  deve ser lida como: pegue a sub-sequência a partir do começo, até 5 posições antes do final, contando de 2 em 2).

Como você provavelmente sabe, todas as operações em objetos de Python são traduzidas internamente para chamadas aos métodos "mágicos" os que tem nome pré-definido  - a melhor documentação para esses métodos é o 'data model" da linguagem, neste endereço: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Em particular, quando vamos obter, fazer uma atribuição ou apagar (com o comando `del`) uma sub-sequência dentro de uma sequência o Python chama respectivamente os métodos `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` e `__delitem__` da classe do objeto que representa a sequência.

Nesse processo, o Python transforma os números colocados na notação de fatia entre colchetes em um objeto `slice`. Ou seja, o Python mesmo chama a "função" `slice` para nós.

O objeto `slice` por sua vez é bem simples, podemos ver a documentação ou introspecta-lo usando o `dir`:

```
In [75]: a = slice(1, 4)


In [76]: dir(a)
Out[76]: 
[...
 'indices',
 'start',
 'step',
 'stop']
```

(eu suprimi os métodos mágicos do slice por que não são importantes) - se você olhar o "start", "step" e "stop", são correspondentes aos atributos que passamos para início e fim da sequência, e "None" para `step` (passo), que é o terceiro argumento opcional)

O método `indices` requer um inteiro representado o tamanho da sequência - e tudo o que ele faz é, levando em conta o comprimento da sequência passado como parâmetro, calcula  os índices de início, final e passo já levando em conta os parâmetros omitidos (ou seja, deixados em branco antes ou depois do  `:`), índices negativos, e etc... Os valores retornados pela chamada ao método`indice` podem ser usados diretamente na "função" `range` para gerar todos os índices daquela fatia.

É mais fácil visualizar com um exemplo: vamos criar uma subclasse de `list` que sempre retorne todos os elementos de uma fatia transformados em strings:

```
class StringSliceList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, indices):
         if isinstance(indices, slice):
              results = []
              start, stop, step = indices.indices(len(self))
              for i in range(start, stop, step):
                   results.append(str(super().__getitem__(i)))
         else:   
            results = super().__getitem__(indices)
         return results
```

pronto, com isso podemos brincar no terminal interativo:

```
In [84]: a = StringSliceList(range(20))

In [85]: a[5:10]
Out[85]: ['5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

O objeto slice *pode* ser passado diretamente entre colchetes, mas ele sempre vai ser menos legível do que usar diretamente a notação com ":":

```
In [86]: a[slice(5,10)]
Out[86]: ['5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Eu acredito que sua manutenção como um built-in por padrão do Python seja mais um lapso do que outra coisa - é uma classe que poderia muito bem estar no módulo `types`. Mas como isso ficou na transição para o Python 3, também é algo muito pouco importante para quebrar a compatibilidade, então ele vai ficando.

## Trivia:

No caso de um índice multi-dimensional, em que vários eixos são separados por `,` dentro dos colchetes, como são os usados em matrizes do NumPy, cada componente separado por `,` pode ser convertido para um objeto `slice` separado.

```
class Test:
   def __getitem__(self, indices):
       print(indices)
```

Pode ser usado:

```
In [89]: Test()[1:10, :, -1:5:10]
(slice(1, 10, None), slice(None, None, None), slice(-1, 5, 10))
```

E isso não acontece se você colocar um par extra de () dentro dos [], por que isso cria uma tupla que não tem os compontentes convertido para objetos do tipo `slice`:

```
In [90]: Test()[(1:10, :, -1:5:10)]
  File "<ipython-input-90-32002bdbab86>", line 1
    Test()[(1:10, :, -1:5:10)]
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score -1):

Slice em uma lista seria o equivalente a usar: ":"

```
input = ['laranja','limão','melancia','mamão']
print(input[1:-1])
```

Há inúmeras formas de você delimitar uma lista. Veja esta pergunta no stack em inglês, eles explicam muito bem o uso do slice:

[Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: desculpe pelo downvote, mas a pergunta é sobre o built-in `slice` não sobre a slice notation .

Comment: De boas, eu entendi.