# : column na frente de varíavel

Tags: python

Opa, voltando com a questão de column antes da variável. Exemplo que estou vendo em python em recurring neural.
`arr = arr[:n_batches * batches_size]`
o que significa o `:n_batches`   ?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Favor detalhar sua pergunta, pois está muito genérica

Comment: Esse `:var` é chamado de `slice`, uma operação especial em vetores. Você encontra mais informação nessa pergunta (e em seus links e suas respostas): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/265588/64969

Answer (score 1):

Isso se chama *slice*. Com ele você consegue acessar uma fatia de um objeto que é iterável. Por exemplo, fazer `lista[1:5]` você estaria acessando os itens de 1 a 4 (o 5 representa o primeiro índice não incluso da fatia). Quando omitido o primeiro valor, será considerado a fatia desde o início do iterador. Ou seja, fazer `lista[:5]` é o equivalente a `lista[0:5]`. Se o segundo valor for omitido, será considerado até o final do mesmo. Isto é, fazer `lista[5:]` seria pegar todos os valores a partir do índice 5 até o final. Se ambos os números forem omitidos, pegará o iterador do início ao fim, fazendo uma cópia raza do seu objeto.

No seu caso,

```
arr = arr[:n_batches * batches_size]
```

Você está acessando o iterável `arr` desde o início até o resultado da multiplicação `n_batches * batches_size`. O equivalente seria:

```
arr = arr[0:n_batches * batches_size]
```

Veja alguns outros exemplos:

```
lista = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print(lista[1:5])  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(lista[:5])   # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(lista[1:])   # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(lista[:])    # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SphericalFemaleComputing) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ZyzFr2)</sup>

Comment: E a estrela `*` seria uma multiplicação normal?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim, basicamente pegando do início até o resultado da multiplicação.