# Como melhorar/otimizar um código de conversão de imagem colorida para escala de cinza

Tags: python

Eu estou testando transformar uma imagem em preto e branco na unha e consegui utilizando o seguinte código.

```
import cv2

imagem = cv2.imread("goku-jr.jpg")


for coluna in imagem:
    for pixel in coluna:
        media = int(sum(pixel)/3)
        pixel [0] = media
        pixel [1] = media
        pixel [2] = media

cv2.imwrite("teste_cinza.jpg",imagem)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu sei que esta não é a melhor forma de transformar em escala de cinza porém utilizei este método para estudo.O que me incomodou foi o for dentro de for, existe alguma possibilidade de escrever este código de uma maneira mais performática e mais elegante?

Obs: Não sei se posso usar este tipo de imagem , qualquer coisa deleto.

Comment: O que seria o objeto `imagem2`?

Comment: Errei o nome , era só imagem.

Comment: Sobre o `for` dentro do `for`: não há problemas nenhum em relação a isso. Na quantidade de pixels, seu programa executa em tempo linear. Acontece apenas que, para enxergar os pixels, você precisa navegar nas colunas separadamente, mas isso não implica que o seu programa execute em tempo quadrático em relação ao número de pixels. Falo mais disso [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/268362/64969)

Comment: acho que da para usar o modulo itertools, la tem o chain, mas isso só vai diminuir uma linha no seu codigo,  ou nem isso, se contar a importação

Comment: "Na unha" quer dizer que `cv2.cvtColor(imagem, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` não serve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problema

Uma imagem é uma matriz, então é possível utilizar o Python ou uma biblioteca, como o Numpy, para evitar o uso de for loops.

Olhando [o Wiki de escala cinza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale), é possível verificar a seguinte fórmula: `Y = 0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B`.

O Python pode ser utilizado com [slice](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/265733/75104) na matriz. Em que cada pixel de uma imagem é composta da seguinte maneira `[linha, coluna, canal]`. E uma imagem no espaço de cores RGB possui três canais, o R,G e B. Portanto, cada pixel possui um array representando o canal `(R,G,B)`.

> Mas atente-se ao fato de que o OpenCV utiliza por padrão o BGR
>   (`(B,G,R)`)

Então é possível verificar a otimização com o código a seguir:

```
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request


# Carregar imagem da internet
resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWQJc.jpg")
imagem = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
imagem = cv2.imdecode(imagem, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Carregar imagem do PC
# imagem = cv2.imread("goku-jr.jpg")

# FOR LOOPS

start_time = time.time()

for coluna in imagem:
    for pixel in coluna:
        media = int(sum(pixel)/3)
        pixel [0] = media
        pixel [1] = media
        pixel [2] = media

cv2.imwrite("OWQJc1.jpg",imagem)
print("--- %s segundos ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

# MATRIZES E ARRAYS

# Carregar imagem da internet
resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWQJc.jpg")
imagem = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
imagem = cv2.imdecode(imagem, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Carregar imagem do PC
# imagem = cv2.imread("goku-jr.jpg")

start_time = time.time()

imagem = 0.0722 * imagem[:, :, 0] + 0.7152 * imagem[:, :, 1] + 0.2126 * imagem[:, :, 2]
imagem = imagem.astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite("OWQJc2.jpg",imagem)
print("--- %s segundos ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

### Resultado

No meu computador, o seguinte resultado foi obtido:

```
--- 0.2000114917755127 segundos ---
--- 0.008000612258911133 segundos ---
```

É possível verificar que o método utilizando os for loops está ligeiramente errado comparando as imagens a seguir:

#### Resultado 1:

[image: resultado for loops]

#### Resultado 2:

[image: Resultado Matrizes]